# Doubt on induced voltage

Tags: electromagnetism

Honestly, this is a homework question.

Below you could see the description of the question

[image]

Here you have the relevant answer.

[image]

---

### My argument

*Here we can neglect answer number 1 and 4*

Reason :

- According to the given diagram we can say current travels form **X** to **Y** , which ultimately leads to have  a lesser potential at X than that of Y, because at X you can find more electrons( I am not quite sure about the direction of current , so I hope you would help me)

  (potential at X=  Vx ), (potential at Y = Vy  )

$$V_X < V_Y$$

Therefore I can say potential at X must be negative relative to that of Y.

But after that I am stuck on finding relavent magnitudes. My argument may be wrong , I don't know exactly.

I am happy to hear your argument towards this question which  might be different.And I want to say,if you can explain this fully from A-Z that would be great. If you can't that okay.

So  what is your answer for this ?

Comment: There is never less wire moving through the field than there just was.

Comment: Imagine that X and Y are connected outside the field so that a current can flow through the metal wire. The current induced in each vertical section must be such that it creates a circular field that opposes motion; i.e. it strengthens the main field in the direction of motion. Consider each vertical section in turn, as they enter the main field, to determine the relevant current directions.

Comment: Chu :Could you explain more about , why does the horizontal parts doesn't effect to B field .

Comment: A conductor must CUT the magnetic field lines for an emf, and hence current, to be generated. Each vertical section will appear as an emf with appropriate polarity, and all the emf's add algebraically to produce the overall emf across XY. If the loop is closed between X and Y the individual currents due to each emf will add - just like having a number of batteries connected in series.

Comment: I am still confused ,anyone out there who could help me to solve this problem.

Comment: There's a vertical section of conductor that's about to enter the field and travel through it at a constant velocity. Given Lenz's law, if a current were to flow through that section, which direction would that be and why? The horizontal sections do not contribute any emf or current, so what happens as the shape continues to move through the field?

Comment: @  Chu: Why horizontal section doesn't contribute to  any emf or current?

Comment: Because a conductor needs to cut lines of force to generate an emf/current. The horizontal sections are not cutting field lines, they're travelling through the field like a javelin. The vertical conductor sections are cutting field lines like a chainsaw. the javelin encounters little opposition; the chain saw does encounter resistance to motion, and therefore does more work and converts that work into electrical energy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25034/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-chu).

Comment: @chu : could you explain this scenario form A-Z?

Comment: I cannot say it more simply than: if a conductor is cutting magnetic field lines at a constant velocity, a constant emf is generated; if a conductor is not cutting magnetic field lines no emf is generated, regardless of velocity. Your teacher must have covered this with you to have given you this problem to solve.

Comment: Could you tell me why horizontal  section doesn't cut the B field , because I feel it is same as the vertical section.

Comment: If you had to carry a ladder on your shoulder through a forest, would the ladder be pointing in your direction of travel, or at 90 degrees to your direction of travel?

Comment: @chu : It would  be pointed towards the direction I travel.

Comment: The B-field is the trees and the ladder is the conductor. The more work you have to do in moving the conductor, the more emf is induced.

Comment: @chu: Still I couldn't understand what you had said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a wire moves across the B field, a voltage is induced across it. This emf will be proportional to the field (constant), velocity (constant) and length of wire perpendicular to the velocity (different segments, different values).

I will label the segments from X to Y as A, B, C, D, E, F and G.

[image]

Segments A, C, E, and G will give rise to an e.m.f. since the wire is moving at right angles to its length. The first three of these give rise to an emf of the same polarity - the last one (G) will reduce the emf a bit.

So we're looking at either (3) or (4). But which is it? For this we need to know the polarity. Now the B field is out of the paper (that is the meaning of the little dot in a circle at the edge of the diagram - you are looking at the tip of an arrow; if the field was into the paper you would see a cross).

A positive charge moving from left to right in the page would feel a downward force due to the B field. This follows from the expression for the Lorentz force:

$$F = q(\vec{E} + \vec{v}\times\vec{B})$$

With \$\vec{v}\$ pointing to the right, and \$\vec{B}\$ pointing towards you, the force \$\vec{F}\$ must point down. If the positive charge is moved down, we are left with a negative potential at the top of the wire.

This means that (3) is the correct answer.

Just to clarify - the point (1) corresponds to the moment that segment C enters the field (t=0); at (2), segment A enters - increasing the e.m.f. A very short time later (3), E enters the field. We now have the largest amount of wire "all pointing the same way". Finally, at time (4) segment G enters the magnetic field; this will reduce the e.m.f. as it is pointing the other way (following the wire from X to Y, A, C and E point down; but G points up).

Comment: B field is out of the paper . There is a dot . Isn't it

Comment: OK - bad eyes. I realized this when I zoomed in. Fixed.

Comment: But the answer in marking scheme is (3),

Comment: Hey did you notice that , here we need to find potential at x relative to y?

Comment: It's late here... see whether you can figure out how I got the polarity wrong.

Comment: Okay floris, I'll try

Comment: Please give me a perfect explanation for this question.

Comment: Could you explain this question form A-Z, a kind request from me.

Comment: May we move this to chat ?

Comment: No. I have updated the answer. I cannot be clearer than this.

Comment: E.M.F induced  only when length of wire perpendicular to the velocity.?

Comment: Perpendicular, or "has a perpendicular projection". A wire at 45° would also induce emf, but \$\sqrt{2}\$ less than if it was perpendicular. Think of a loop moving into a field. The area increases because there is a wire that was not parallel to the velocity, that is a part of the loop...

Comment: What if I move the wires which not in shape of straight lines, like circles, cones like stuffs ?

Comment: Hence the "projection" comment. It is midnight here.

Comment: At the moment New england usa time is  12:07 AM, isn't it. So do you available after 8-9 hours from now. Any way your answers helped me lot. I wished , you'd be my teacher

Comment: :I have few questions to get clear. I seek your help

Comment: I need your help

Comment: Do you like to move this into a chat ?

Comment: could you explain this [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/177976/about-induced-current)

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Faraday's law of induction and deduce the correct behavior.

\begin{gather}
V_x - V_y = \frac{d}{dt} \iint_{\Sigma} \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{S} = - \oint_{\partial \Sigma} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l}
\end{gather}
\$V_x - V_y\$ is the potential you want to find, \$\Sigma\$ is any control surface, \$\vec{B}\$ is the magnetic field, and \$d\vec{S}\$ is the calculus infinitesimal integral surface element. The last path integral we will ignore for now, though it will be important later for determining the sign. The important bit is that my path integral goes from point y to point x.

If we define our control surface to be the area enclosed by the wire which is inside the magnetic field, then \$\vec{B}\$ is a constant. Re-arrange the equation:

\begin{gather}
V_x - V_y = \vec{B} \cdot \hat{n} \frac{d}{dt} \iint_{\Sigma} dS\\
V_x - V_y = \vec{B} \cdot \hat{n} \frac{dA}{dt}
\end{gather}

Where \$A\$ is the surface area of the control surface and \$\hat{n}\$ is the control surface normal.
The question now becomes at what rate is our control surface area changing? The answer to that question is the answer you desire.

The last question is to determine the sign: are \$\hat{n}\$ and \$\vec{B}\$ pointing in the same direction? If they are, then \$V_x > V_y\$. Otherwise, \$V_y > V_x\$. To figure this out, use the [right-hand rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule): wrap your fingers in the direction of the path integral, then the direction your thumb is pointing will denote the direction of \$\hat{n}\$.

Comment: Hey, what is the last path integral.( I just started to read your answer)

Comment: The integral of the electric field. It's there just to show where the potential difference comes from.

Comment: Why you put two integral symbols. ( Still I am  a beginner)

Comment: It's a surface integral, i.e. a "2D" integral.

Comment: It means you used it to indicate this whole scenario happen in 2D ?

Comment: Yes and no. You are integrating on a 2D surface, but that surface may exist in 3D space. Think of the difference between surface area and volume.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25024/discussion-between-on-the-way-to-success-and-helloworld922).

Comment: I am confused about this thing,  \begin{gather}
V_x - V_y = \vec{B} \cdot \hat{n} \frac{d}{dt} \iint_{\Sigma} dS\\
V_x - V_y = \vec{B} \cdot \hat{n} \frac{dA}{dt}
\end{gather}. Could you explain it bit simpler

Comment: B is constant so it is possible to move it outside the integral. However, it's a surface integral of a vector field so appropriate magic needs to happen to ensure the end result is a scalar, hence the dot product with the surface normal, which also happens to be constant in this case so it moves out of the integral as well. The surface integral of 1 is just the surface area. I'll try to think of a simpler explanation which doesn't involve calculus since I suspect this is material you haven't been exposed to yet in your classes.

Answer (score -1):

Voltage induced=flux density(B)* length of conductor perpendicular to the direction of movement(ln)* velocity.  voltage=B* sum X*Vel hence 3 or 4 correct answer depending upon the Direction offlux. vtingole