# About induced current

Tags: electromagnetism

This is a homework question that I have stuck for a while and couldn't able to come up with the correct answer.

So here is the question,

[image]

**My thoughts towards this question**

- When I move the  rod PQ with a constant velocity ,the area of
  triangle RPQ inside the magnetic field increases .
- Once the area inside the magnetic field increases E.M.F induces also
  increases.
- Since induce E.M.F get increased the induced current should also be
  increased.

So according to my arguments  I choose the answer as the third one. But the answer in marking scheme is the first one.

What I have done wrong. Please explain this question with details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question asks for the current, not the voltage.

The voltage (emf) generated would follow a straight line (not a curve) as the rate at which the area grows is proportional to the length of the wire - and the length of the wire grows linearly.

The current that flows as a result of this depends on the resistance of the loop. The circumference of the loop grows linearly with the horizontal position of the wire (similar triangles - when the wire has moved twice as far to the right, all the sides are twice as big).

The current is voltage divided by resistance. Both grow linearly; their ratio is constant.

Comment: Please floris explain little bit more , specially the theory parts I want to use . A kind request

Comment: your first two bullet points are exactly right, but then you need Ohm's Law: I = V / R. And R scales with the length of the wire, just like V did. There is really nothing more to say.

Comment: I think ,we need to move this to a chat, isn't it?

Comment: Because I have confused with some facts

Comment: Or please explain this with more , like you did in previous questions.You helped me lot Mr.floris

Comment: Floris: How to solve this [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178325/how-to-choose-the-correct-graph)

Comment: Floris: Did you check this [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178325/how-to-choose-the-correct-graph)

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess - yes I did. I am not sure how to answer it.

Comment: floris :  Actually I can not believe that, because  you helped  me like a genius, and of course that answers really helped me. So  I wonder why can't you answer this.(I am not sure why you can't)?

Comment: None of the graphs look right to me so there must be something I am not getting. You should ask your teacher.

Comment: then let's move this to a chat

Comment: @floris-What is the way to solve this  [question?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178917/correct-graph-for-induced-e-m-f)

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess - what is wrong with the answers you already have? You seem to be feeding this site with a constant barrage of questions of the "do my homework for me" variety. That is not what this is for...

Comment: @floris-I thought you have a short way to do that question, if you don't know such an easy  way  that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage (or EMF) between P & Q is a constant given constant length, velocity and magnetic field, lets call it V.

The voltage between R & S is RS/PQ V, the induced current is through RBQ  is equal to RS/PQ V/R by Ohms law.

Let L be the distance to the right of B that the wire is.

RS=2Ltan30

Assuming constant resistivity in the wire (r),

R=4Lrtan30

So, I = 2Ltan30/PQ V / 4Lrtan30 = V/2PQr

Which is independent of L

Comment: Could you explain this little bit more ?