# Findning the magnitude of the current

Tags: current, electromagnetism

Screen shot of the question  is given below.

[image]

---

### My thoughts

- Since the B field  into the page  is decreasing, and induced current is induced in such a way to oppose that condition. So here I can find the induced E.M.F.Becasue induced E.M.F equals to the rate of change of magnetic flux .Then by that argument I find the induced E.M.F, you can find the math part I have done to find it,

$$E.M.F= B*A$$

$$E.M.F= 150*(0.1)^2$$

$$Induced E.M.F= 1.5 V$$

- Therefore I can find induced current ,
  $$induced current =1.5V/10= 0.015A$$
- And the current drawn form the cell is equals to **o.20A**.

So my question is do I need to get the sum of these two values or subtract them?

Once I use the right-hand rule to detect the direction of induced current , I found it as the direction opposite to the current draws from the cell. You can see clearly see what I am talking about by looking the below image,

[image]

- Let **I0** be the current draws from the cell.

*So what I need to do here ?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that emf is 1.5V but I didn't like the formula used. It should be: -

emf = B.A/t (flux density x area divided by time)

Also you have used 0.01m as the length of one side and this is incorrect - it is 0.1m. All the same you got the correct answer of 1.5 volts!!

Then you go and say the induced current is 0.015 amps - this is incorrect it is 0.15 amps i.e. 1.5 volts divided by 10 ohms.

Direction of current induced can be gleaned from this: -

[image]

The image above is for a loop getting bigger and this is the same as the field increasing linearly whilst the loop stays the same size. [Link](http://www.physics.sjsu.edu/becker/physics51/induction.htm). If the loop were getting smaller, this would be equivalent to the scenario in the question and therefore the direction of current would be opposite to that shown in the diagram above.

So the induced current is subtracting from the standing current of 0.5 amps to produce a current of 0.35 amps. Or just look at it in terms of the net voltage being 3.5 volts across a ten ohm resistor.

Comment: Actually I mistakenly write the length as 0.01 . It should be 0.1. I got the induced emf as 1.5v because I did this question earlier and stuck  ,so I wrote it as 1.5v

Comment: @Onthewaytosuccess Yeah I was just picking on you for writing such a sloppy question LOL. I originally got it wrong in my answer and had to edit it. I'm normally pretty good with magnetics but I seem to have a blind spot on direction of current sometimes.

Comment: I think 3.5 volts across a ten ohm resistor is better, isn't it?

Comment: Hey Andy can you take  a look at this [question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/178840/how-to-determine-the-correct-graph-for-induced-current)

Comment: "The image above is for a loop getting bigger and this is the same as the field increasing linearly whilst the loop stays the same size." Is this true if the field is out of the page ?

Comment: If the field is out of the page then the induced emf is opposite and so the current would be additive with the static current from 5V source.